# Class delegation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Trait delegation is described in docs, and there are no questions. But what about class delegation?

```
class FrameWorkClass // Third party class we cannot modify
class MyDerivedFrameWorkClass(c:FrameWorkClass) : FrameWorkClass by c
```

What is the best way to achieve this without modifying FrameWorkClass? Obviously we are unable to make it implement our interface.

Comment: note, `trait` in Kotlin has been renamed to `interface`

Comment: I added an answer to try and clarify the situation, there is not another option besides something as described by @damien or my slight variation.

Answer (score 5):

You can only delegate an interface to a variable that implements that interface.  You cannot delegate directly to another class.  As @Damian was pointing out; basically is simplified as:

```
interface Framework {}
class FrameWorkImpl: Framework {}
class MyDerivedFrameWorkClass(val fw: FrameWorkImpl) : Framework by fw {}
```

Or you can generically say:

```
class MyDerivedFrameWorkClass(val fw: Framework) : Framework by fw {}
```

to accept any implementation of the Framework interface and delegate to it, so `FrameworkImpl` and `FrameworkHappyDays` both work if they implement the `Framework` interface.

This is updated to current Kotlin, where `trait` has been renamed to `interface`

Comment: It looks like this is delegating (pun intended) the choice of the delegated class to the consumer. Fortunately, there is an alternative: `class MyDerivedFrameworkClass : Framework by FrameworkImpl() {...}`.

Answer (score -1):

At the moment only traits can be delegated like this. If you have a class that you would like to delegate, I would simply take that class and extract a trait(interface) including all the methods you are interested in. Here is an example based on your code.

Imagine you have these classes:

```
class FrameWorkClass {
        fun foo() {}

        fun boo() {}
    }
class MyDerivedFrameWorkClass(c:FrameWorkClass) : FrameWorkClass by c
```

It does not compile right? Let's say you are interested in `foo()`

```
trait FrameWorkTrait {
    fun foo() {}
}
class FrameWorkClassImpl: FrameWorkTrait {
    override fun foo() {}

    fun boo() {}
}
class MyDerivedFrameWorkClass(c:FrameWorkTrait) : FrameWorkTrait by c
```

At least this is how I would do it.

Comment: Actually it doesn't help, and won't be possible in current version of Kotlin. What I need is: some api provides me `FrameWorkClass` which I want to delegate to my `MyDerivedFrameWorkClass`. In your solution I have to delegate `FrameWorkClassImpl` which should be wrapped above api provided class.

Comment: It's a bit unclear for me what you need. Could you please add more details to your question? Regarding possibilities in Kotlin, I have tried this code and it worked for me in current Kotlin version.